# Is it possible: a function inside a struct, which acts upon data members of the same struct, without having to provide a self-reference of the struct?

Tags: c, oop, struct

I would like to implement OOP behaviour in C, but just a small aspect of it, which is data encapsulation (in the example below the data is exposed, but only to keep the example simple) and method calling. Let's say we have a struct:

```
struct _Object_
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int (*sum)(int x , int y);
};      

typedef struct _Object_ Object;

//this function's pointer will be added to the struct. Constructor isn't shown here.
int sumNumbers(int x, int y)   /
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Now the way C permits me to use the struct is:

```
int result;
Calculator.x = 3;
Calculator.y = 5;

result = Calculator.sum(calculator.x, calculator.y);
```

which is somewhat tedious and seems redundant. What I would like to achieve, is to be able to use it in a similar fashion to C++, i.e. that the `sumNumbers` function wouldn't require arguments, but would access them directly from the struct, like so:

```
int sumNumbers(void)
{
    return reference_to_struct_which_called_this_method.x + reference_to_struct_which_called_this_method.y;
}

int result;
Calculator.x = 3;
Calculator.y = 5;

result = Calculator.sum();
```

So the main idea is to load up my struct with data and methods and then use it without the need to always supply a self-reference of the struct to the methods the same struct is calling. Is this doable in C?

Solutions I don't want or can use:

- MACROS
- Workarounds that include dynamic memory allocation

P.S. I am not looking for answers of the type "why aren't you using C++ instead, if you need OOP" etc. The code I provided also isn't meant to compile, just to illustrate an idea.

Comment: Keep in mind though that your `sum` in the structure definition is not a procedure, it's a pointer. Second, your "OOP example" is lacking somewhat -- why does a "member" of a structure need to sum two arbitrary numbers, isn't it supposed to sum the numbers contained in the structure it belongs to? Why would you even need a reference to an object ("self") if you aren't adding the numbers the structure would contain?

Comment: @amn: The first example, where the member of the struct can sum two arbitrary numbers, was just one solution to how it could be done (although a very poor one). Replacing `int (*sum)(int x, int y)` with `int (*sum)(Calculator *this)` as @mnistic suggested, is already a step in the right direction, although it still requires me to provide the reference of the struct as an argument. I actually want the "method" to act upon "data members", but only upon the data members of this struct and not some other struct you could potentially provide via pointer by mistake.

Comment: What you are specifically asking for would require a compiler extension and would not be standard-compliant C. I am not aware of such extensions... All you can do in the meantime to prevent accidentally passing the wrong pointer would be to use macros for method invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you would have to pass the object to the function:

```
struct Calculator
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int (*sum)(struct Calculator*);
};      

typedef struct Calculator Calculator;

int sum(Calculator* this)
{
    return this->x + this->y;
}

int main(void) {
    int result;
    Calculator calc;
    calc.x = 3;
    calc.y = 5;
    calc.sum = sum;

    result = calc.sum(&calc);
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

For more information, see: https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. The structure allocates space for a pointer to a procedure, this space is available as `sum`. When creating an instance of the structure, the space is typically (but not always) left uninitialized -- your structure neither embeds nor by default references an actual procedure of the form `int (int, int)` (a procedure that takes two arguments of type `int` and which returns a value of type `int`). A pointer to a procedure and the procedure itself aren't the same thing.

Conceptually, your `sum` member of the structure is an *interface* -- it specifies what kind of function shall be stored as `sum` but it leaves out an implementation. Let's say you have a straightforward sum procedure defined:

```
int sum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

That's an implementation -- an actual procedure that will be residing somewhere in memory. Now, if you have an object `obj` of type `struct _Object_` declared with `struct _Object_ obj;` statement, you can initialize its `sum` member to point at said procedure:

```
obj.sum = sum;
```

Regarding your question about how a procedure can conveniently be invoked on a structure it "belongs to", `obj.sum(x, y)` won't do -- the procedure pointed to by `obj.sum` may be any procedure stored in a location in memory that bears no relation to the address of the object ("data" in OOP lingo) that embeds the pointer to the procedure. Meaning that the procedure, when called, cannot automatically determine if there is a particular object it "is called on". Many arbitrary objects may be referencing the same procedure through their `sum` or other pointers, while the procedure itself is a body of code residing at an [unrelated to an object] address in memory, as such it needs to be explicitly provided a reference to an object [to work with]. Which is what [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58820575/254343) explains.

But I said "yes and no" for a reason: *the address* of the pointer to the procedure you are calling *is* absolutely related to the data the procedure will operate on, and the compiler knows how because it is provided the structure layout. If we step back one level of indirection -- if we have the address of the `sum` pointer (not the address stored *in* the pointer, i.e. not the pointer's value), provided the structure layout is known, it is possible to construct a "member" procedure call that "automagically" may access an object it is "invoked on":

```
struct _Object_ {
    int x;
    int y;
    int (*sum)(struct _Object_ * self, ...);
};

obj.sum(&(obj.sum) - sizeof(int) * 2, ...); /** This is unsafe because the exact offset depends on alignment and internal structure layout, something best known to the compiler. */
//or, conventionally
obj.sum(&obj, ...);
```

The entire premise rests on the fact that knowing where the object is, we can invoke a procedure one of the function pointers embedded in the object points at, and we can pass the object address to said procedure, too.

I don't think you can avoid all the unnecessary verbosity without macros, though:

```
#define MESSAGE(obj, message) (obj.message(&obj))
```

Now you can call the `sum` member of `obj` (or "pass a [`sum`] message to `obj`", as it is also called -- hence my macro above being called `MESSAGE`), without knowing the implementation of `sum` that will be invoked, as follows:

```
MESSAGE(obj, sum)
```

Anyway, save for one important difference, this is how virtual functions and virtual function tables work in C++. The important difference is that with C++, an object typically does not reserve space for its own procedures -- as opposed to using procedures of *its class*. Meaning that if you were to implement C++ class model, you wouldn't be having one pointer for every procedure you want for a class -- in your `struct` definition -- but instead you'd have a single pointer to the *class* structure, which in turn will contain the procedure pointers. The pointer for an entire class of objects will point to the same class object across your entire program:

```
struct _Object_Class { /// This is a de-facto virtual function table
    int (*sum)(struct _Object_ * self, ...);
    /// Other procedures that one considers members of this class
} 

struct _Object_ {
    struct _Object_Class * clazz;
    /// Object data
    int x;
    int y;
}

int sum(struct _Object_ * self, ...) {
    return self->x + self->y;
}

struct _Object_Class clazz = { .sum = sum };

struct _Object_ obj = { .clazz = clazz };

#define MESSAGE(obj, message, ...) obj.clazz->message(&obj, ...)

obj.x = 1;
obj.y = 2;

int z = MESSAGE(obj, sum);
```

I may have omitted proper passing of variable number of arguments to procedures, but it isn't important here.

Class inheritance is then implemented by having objects of different classes refer to function tables (`struct _Object_Class` above) of their own preferred class. The difference between these tables is what will define which methods will be actually invoked when you message the object with a particular method identity.

The first C++ compiler generated C code that then was fed to a C compiler. The techniques described above are covered in more depth in [the article](https://www.cs.rit.edu/%7Eats/books/ooc.pdf) linked by the other answer.

Comment: I'd forget about using `obj.sum(&(obj.sum) - sizeof(int) * 2, ...);` as that seems particularly unsafe and incorrect (it ignores structure padding and does pointer arithmetic incorrectly).

Comment: For `#define MESSAGE(obj, message) (obj.message(&obj))`, you really need parentheses around `obj`: `#define MESSAGE(obj, message) ((obj).message(&(obj)))`.

Comment: @amn: kudos to your really clever solution. Using pointer arithmetic is ingenious, although in this case unsafe (as Ian Abbott pointed out) . The reason why I am not marking this as the solution is because it is using macros, and on of the conditions I stated was that I do not want to use macros. Still the information you provided is extremely valuable.

Comment: The example with manually calculating the address of the object was just an example, I completely agree that it's unsafe, but I chose to include it for the sake of completeness. I have edited the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Two comments: First, if you make the `sum` function pointer the first member of the structure, by the C standard the address of the `sum` member must be the address of the full structure, so you wouldn't need to do any dodgy pointer arithmetic to get the other structure members.  Second:  identifiers that start with one underscore and then a capital letter (or two underscores) are reserved identifiers and should not be used.

Comment: @AndrewHenle How will having `sum` as first member of the structure help if you've (and as is typical) got multiple member functions like that in the structure? No dodgy arithmetic is required anyway -- the arithmetics I show is just an example, and I warn against using it. The simple way to call a member function would be `obj.sum(&obj, ...)` which is as straightforward as it gets without macros, and is in most scenarios inferior to utilizing function tables as demonstrated in the second part of my answer. Regarding reserved identifiers, I wanted to follow the naming choices in the question.

Comment: The structure padding could be handled by using `offsetof` instead of manually adding sizes of members.

Comment: *No dodgy arithmetic is required anyway*  Yes, it's dodgy because it ignores the possibility of padding within that structure.  @Gerhardh pointed out that you can use the `offsetof()` operator to get the number of bytes between a structure member and the start of the structure itself.

Comment: That's not what I meant -- `obj.method(&obj)` is not dodgy and works for all cases of structures, padding, alignment and object layouts otherwise. `offsetof` isn't required either, obviously. But I agree that it's an objectively better solution than doing something like `sizeof(int) * 2`, which is badly tied to a whole bunch of variables. Anyway, I am not sure exactly what part of my answer is being debated. Is there something wrong with `obj.method(&obj)`?